# How to use LIMIT with my given query

Tags: mysql

```
    $sql = "
SELECT *
FROM teacher_uploads
where view_counts in (SELECT view_counts
                      from teacher_uploads
                      ORDER BY view_counts DESC
                     ) and
      subject_id = $subject_id";
```

now i want to fetch all max view_counts
 limit by 2

Comment: Please provide table structure too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT tu.*
FROM teacher_uploads tu JOIN
     (SELECT view_counts
      FROM teacher_uploads
      ORDER BY view_counts DESC
      LIMIT 2
     ) ttu
     ON tu.view_counts = ttu.view_counts
WHERE subject_id = $subject_id;
```

Note:  You probably want the `WHERE` clause in the subquery as well.  However, that is not the query in your question.

Comment: i am using single table

Comment: @shabirullah . . . And this query only references one table.

Comment: what does tu and ttu means and i am getting only first max view counts how to fetch first 2 max view counts

Comment: These are table aliases.  MySQL requires that derived tables have names, so that is one use of table aliases.

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM teacher_uploads 
 WHERE view_counts IN (SELECT view_counts 
                         FROM teacher_uploads 
                        ORDER 
                           BY view_counts DESC )  
   AND subject_id = $subject_id 
 LIMIT 2"
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless